# How to create a 2 column drop-down navigation header in Volusion

Tags: navigation, e-commerce, volusion

Currently, I cannot find where my custom navigation is located on the Volusion platform. I have top navigation and since I am adding more subcategories, need to be able to create two columns in the drop down instead of one ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5a1s.jpg))

Does anyone know where I can access the navigation and how to revise the code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anywhere in Volusion where you can control the HTML output of the navigation.

Once you assign your categories to a menu, and that menu is used in your current/active template, Volusion renders the unordered list (UL) as part of the page output.

If you are looking to split a list into multiple columns, consider css changes and modifying the dom with jQuery.  Sadly that is how I end up making most of the customizations that I need to make to the page if they can't be done in Volusion as part of the settings or the template file itself.